# Excel formating

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two sheets, sheet1 is my input while sheet2 is my call list.

Sheet2 consist of two columns, column A (products) and column B (owners)

```
   A         B  
1  Products  Owner  
2  Apple     Red  
3  Grape     Purple
```

Sheet1 is my input. SHEET1 Column B is formatted as so,

```
=IF($A1="","",(VLOOKUP($A1,SHEET2!A:B,2,FALSE)))
```

This being if any product on SHEET2 is present in SHEET1 column A return SHEET2 Column B corresponding data.

SHEET1

```
   A      B      C
1  Grape  Purple 1/17/05  
2  Apple  Red    2/05/06
```

Now to my question. I need to update SHEET2 Column B, new owners for products. When I make this change I do not want it to affect any past entries, while and new entries will get the updated owner.

I believe there is a better formula to do this. The one I am using now does half of what I want, but any change I make on SHEET2 Owner column all of SHEET1 is updated. I want the change to only affect new entries not past entries.

Comment: `When I make this change I do not want it to affect any past entries` Confused by this fact. You want to see all changes, thus keep all old historical data?

Comment: If you want to keep old data, the only way to do that is to keep old data. I would suggest either saving a copy of your spreadsheet to a different file (and possibly making it read-only) or adding new columns for **Owner**, renaming the current ones **Old owner**, or **Owner before 2017-04-20**, or something to that effect.

Comment: I know with the formula I have now it only does half of what I want.  Auto fill the owner based on the product entered.  Though as time goes on these owners change, so I have to update the owner column on SHEET2 so that any new entry auto fills the updated owner but past entries are not effected.  I need it on one file because these "products" have made purchases under an owner. The owner changes but I still need to calculate how much the "product" spent while under X owner.  As of right now I am not doing any kind of auto fill.  Just seeing if I could to cut down on time.

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself a bit. What you want to do is mimic a database. In order to track changes in "owner" you must have duplicate data, there is no way around that. You say "owner" but you give colors, that's not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Now to my question. I need to update SHEET2 Column B, new owners for
>   products. When I make this change I do not want it to affect any past
>   entries, while and new entries will get the updated owner.

Formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,database!A1:C7,2,FALSE)
```

Setup:

- Let's call PRESENT, CURRENT_OWNERS.
- Let's call Sheet1, DATABASE (always SORT on DATE, New to Old)

[image]

[image]

[image]